# Creating function for implementing steepest descent algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matlab, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to implement steepest descent algorithm for minimization of 2D function. Let me explain with example.

I have function `f1(x1,x2) = 2*x1^2 + x2^2 - 5*x1*x2` and starting with initial guess point `p0 = [1,0]`.

Step 1: Initial guess point `p0 = [1,0]`, convergence parameter `e=0.1`

Step 2:  calculate gradient `c1` of `f1` at `p0`. `c1=[4,-5]` I am using central difference method for that.

Step 3: If norm of `c1>e`, go to step 4, otherwise stop.

Step 4: Our direction of search is `d1 = - c1`. So, `d1 = [-4,5]`.

Step 5: Find step size `a` to minimize `f1(a) = f1(p0 +  a*d1) = f1(1-4a,5a)`

Step 6: Update `p0` to `p1` as `p1 = p0 + a * d1` and to to step 2.

I am trying to implement this example in matlab and do not know how to implement step 5. I know that ant 1D search algorithm, such as bisection method can work. But, problem is to 'converting' `f1(1-4a,5a)` to a function, that is, substituting `(1-4a,5a)` into `f1`. I encounter symbolic constant `a` here, which I do not know how to deal with. If I write a minimization function, I can pass values to it, but not sure about symbolic variable `a`. I do not want to use special features of matlab, such as symbolics and trying to keep code at general level, so I can convert it into other programming languages without any problems.  Your suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Please show us the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use `fminbnd` to place some bounds on the line search (-1 to 1 below), since searching the entire line is an ill-defined task. There is no need for a symbolic variable. Step size is determined by minimizing an anonymous function below:

```
a = fminbnd(@(a) f1(p(1) + a*d(1), p(2) + a*d(2)), -1, 1);
```

Here p is the current point and d is the direction of search.  (I wouldn't want to call them p1 and d1 as in your description, as if they are something used for the 1st step only.)

The example allows negative a, which I find helpful in practice; sometimes it's better to go in the opposite direction from what the gradient suggests. To disallow this, change the bounds to 0, 1 (or 0, 10 for a more aggressive search in the forward direction) .